# Can i use Persistent Storage Object for creating a Blackberry application with large number of records?

Tags: blackberry

I want to know that can i use the PersistentStorage Objects to create a database with large number of objects? Does it affect the speed of the Blackberry mobile?

Or is their any other approach i can use for creating a database?

I am using Blackberry Curve 8310( OS - 4.5.0.52).

Please reply.

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,
Richa Bhatia

Answer (score 0):

PersitentStore uses internal phone memory. So the access is very fast but limited to the size of memory available.
Regarding  a more sturdy solution, look at McObject's Perst or Sybase's SQLAnywhere, these are complete database toolkits,but they are commercial.